# Ruby send_data to render an array as PDF in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application where I show Fedex labels in my browser as PDF.

I have used `send_data` to render each label as follows and it works perfectly:

```
 @label_image = Base64.decode64(image_hex).html_safe   #image_hex is a text field where I store the label in db
 send_data @label_image, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline', :filename => 'test.pdf'
```

But, I want to **render multiple labels** in the similar way i.e I can have an array of labels `say @labels_images`  and render them to the browser in one request.

Each page of the PDF should have one label.

How can I do this either using `send_data` or any other library available for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with using [combine_pdf gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) which helps me to merge multiple objects to be rendered in the browser as PDF.

The working code looks like this:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
@label_items.each { |item| pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Base64.decode64(item.image_hex).html_safe) }
send_data pdf.to_pdf, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline', :filename => 'test.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to first create a multi-page pdf, once you have that, you can pass it into `send_data`.

There are lots of pdf libraries in ruby there is a good list on [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation).

Alternatively if you didn't want a multi-page pdf, you could zip up multiple pdfs together into into a single file and pass that to `send_data`.

Comment: thanks for the response, I used combine_pdf gem to get this working!